# What kind of a test plug to use for DWV inspection

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, inspection, rough-in

I'm an owner-builder, getting ready for a close-in inspection which includes plugging and testing the DWV system for a new bathroom. I have a standard 3" test ball that I have used as a test plug in the past, but that was always with a standard sanitary tee. The plumber that I hired used a Y fitting for the cleanout, and the test ball won't work. If I plug the outlet to the Y, then the water will just come through the cleanout. And I can't plug the cleanout separately in this case, because of the chain attached to the test ball.

How do I plug up the DWV system for inspection, when the cleanout uses a standard ABS 45% Y hub?

Answer (score 3):

[Flexible double test plugs](https://www.petersenproducts.com/149-2-Series-Double-Mechanical-Aluminum-Body-Test-s/1914.htm) are what I've used in the past.

[image: flexible double test plug]

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass the test ball into the branch of the wye valve-stem-end first, then work it up into the pipe above the wye inlet, and finally inflate the ball in that position?

Otherwise, if the pipes can move around a bit, perhaps cut the pipe and install the familiar sanitary tee above or below the wye.